# ElasticSearch Query and Filter on Index with Array of Nested Objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch Index setup with the following document structure

```
[
    {
      "id":id,
      "title: "Sample Title",
      "created_at":timestamp
      "categories:[
          {
              "name": "Category 1"
              "image": "image.png",
          },
          {
              "name": "Category 2"
              "image": "image.png",
          },
          {
              "name": "Category 3"
              "image": "image.png",
          },
          {
              "name": "Category 4"
              "image": "image.png",
          },
          ....
      ]
    },
    ....
]
```

This index will contain hundreds of thousands of records in this format.
I'm trying to figure out how to optimally setup a query and structure this data so I can setup a query that will allow me to display a list of categories to the end user in this fashion.

- [image] Category 1  (20)
- [image] Category 2  (30)
- [image] Category 3  (10)

This query would be able to be filtered by the created_at timestamp so that the counts would adjust based on the number of items like such.

- [image] Category 1  (10)
- [image] Category 2  (5)
- [image] Category 3  (25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this figured out.

First off you have to set the mapping explicitly for categories or it will not allow you to using the "nested" property within the aggregation.

```
"mappings": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties":{
        "categories":{
            "type":"nested"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I found out that the best way to approach this is using a "composite" aggregation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

Which will allow me to paginate the aggregations and pull back all the necessary properties.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "list": {
                    "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                                "name": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "categories.name.keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "image": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "categories.image.keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```